# How to create an horizontal Line with dots over it

Tags: html, css, embed

I am doing a school project where I have to create a horizontal line that has some dots over it.

I cannot use css as a separated file. The css needs to be inside the tag of HTML.

For example:

I already created the horizontal line, but I cannot create the dots over it.[image]

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! Please remember to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example. Such as what you've tried so far, what failed, what research you did.

Comment: What you achieve so far? Can you add your html? We do not provide full codes.

Comment: Can you be more specific about what your desired end result is? Do you need the dots to have any functionality? Or are you just asking for a line with dots on it? Should it look like the image above?

Comment: I just need the dots over the horizontal line.
So far, I am only able to create the horizontal line...
I need to place the 5 dots on it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is my solution :

```css
.wraper {
  padding: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  width: 500px;
  margin: 10px auto;
}

h1 {
  margin: 50px auto;
}

.container {
  border-top: 2px solid #000;
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: stretch;
  align-content: stretch;
}

.link {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 10px;
  width: 100%;
}

.link a {
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 15px;
}

.link:first-child {
  margin-left: -55px;
}

.link:last-child {
  margin-right: -55px;
}

.link::after {
  content: "";
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 10px;
  top: -18px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translatex(-50%);
  border: 2px solid black;
}

.active::after,
.link:hover::after {
  background: black;
}

p.lead {
  font-weight: 600;
  margin: 50px auto;
  line-height: 1.5;
}
```

```html
<div class="wraper">
  <h1>How We Work</h1>

  <ul class="container">
    <li class="link"><a href="">Identify</a></li>
    <li class="link"><a href="">Form</a></li>
    <li class="link active"><a href="">Develop</a></li>
    <li class="link"><a href="">Launch</a></li>
    <li class="link"><a href="">Grow</a></li>
  </ul>

  <p class="lead">A streamlined team of co-founders is brought together to create and lead the company, empowering a new generation of entrepreneurs.</p>
</div>
```

Hope you need it :)

Comment: how do I move the text at the top mean above dots and not bottom

Answer (score 3):

You could include something like:

```html
<div style="margin:50px;width:450px;height:25px;overflow:hidden;">
  <div style="width:550px;height:2px;background:black;position:relative;top:5px;">
    <div style="float:left;width:10px;height:10px;background:black;border-radius:50%;position:relative;top:-4px;margin-right:100px;"></div>
    <div style="float:left;width:10px;height:10px;background:black;border-radius:50%;position:relative;top:-4px;margin-right:100px;"></div>
    <div style="float:left;width:10px;height:10px;background:black;border-radius:50%;position:relative;top:-4px;margin-right:100px;"></div>
    <div style="float:left;width:10px;height:10px;background:black;border-radius:50%;position:relative;top:-4px;margin-right:100px;"></div>
    <div style="float:left;width:10px;height:10px;background:black;border-radius:50%;position:relative;top:-4px;margin-right:100px;"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<div style="width:550px;height:2px;position:relative;left:45px;top:-55px;">
    <div style="float:left;width:10px;height:10px;position:relative;top:-4px;margin-right:100px;">text</div>
    <div style="float:left;width:10px;height:10px;position:relative;top:-4px;margin-right:100px;">some other text</div>
    <div style="float:left;width:10px;height:10px;position:relative;top:-4px;margin-right:100px;">some more text</div>
    <div style="float:left;width:10px;height:10px;position:relative;top:-4px;margin-right:100px;">guess what! text!</div>
    <div style="float:left;width:10px;height:10px;position:relative;top:-4px;margin-right:100px;">text again</div>
  </div>
```

The dots have margins on their right to make the spacing and they are position relative to make sure they are on the line. A wrapper has been added to hide an extra part on the right of the black line which was needed due to the right margin on the last dot (otherwise the dot would have gone onto the next line).

You can also add text using the last part of the html code above.